# NDK No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to download the Android NDK and extract the android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin package. The web site says to do the following:

1. `chmod a+x android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin`
2. `./android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin`

Step 2 gives the following errors:  No such file or directory

Any help? This should be easy.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x86_64.

So I was able to run the command after installing all the build tools

I am not sure which one did the trick but it works now:

apt-get install bison build-essential curl flex git-core gnupg gperf libesd0-dev libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libxml2 libxml2-utils lzop openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre pngcrush schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc zip zlib1g-dev

Comment: I did not download OSX binaries. I downloaded the correct ones.

Comment: Okay, then I'm downvoting your question for misrepresenting the facts.  You've quoted the name of the darwin - which is to say OSX - download in the command you appear to be having trouble with.  If that is not the command you are issuing, then **fix your question to reflect the actual commands you are issuing**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a 32bit machine? You can get that error if you're running a 64bit binary on a 32bit machine. Try downloading the 32bit version.

Check your version with: `uname -a` and see if it's x86_64 or not.

The other issue might be that you're missing libraries. You can check by running `ldd [filename]`. I'm going to guess you need to `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 2):

using

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

or using 7z to extract the bin

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
7z x *bin
```

for the reason why (Ubuntu 14.04 64bits / android ndk r10c) will have an error, you can visit https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78148

Answer (score -1):

Which OS are you under?
It seems you downloaded the one for linux.
the instructions are for darwin - mac OS - perhaps you need to change the command to the actual file name.

No such file errors are usually because you either don't have the correct permissions (make sure you typed the file correctly running (1)) or there's a library missing for running the file, in which case try running
    ldd filename
to check if all required local libraries are present.

Comment: More, it looks like the darwin version was downloaded as a self-unpacking executable, and will not unpack itself on linux.